# Trying to access IBM cloud regions outside of the US but fail due to unauth

Tags: ibm-cloud

Trying to use the bluemix golang client library and 'connect' to each region in the world and get our bluemix instance id to issue subsequent resource queries.

However, anything but us-south returns an unauth. I am trying to not use the Cloudfoundry API, so what is the best practice to enable my organization to have the ability to issue resource requests in the different regions? The IAM pages do not appear to have a region association like the Cloudfoundry api has.

Comment: How did you start and find all regions?

Comment: @data_henrik I had to look at the SDK source code.

Answer (score 0):

This cobra command structure appears to solve the problem.

```
package cmd

import (
    "github.com/IBM-Cloud/bluemix-go"
    "github.com/IBM-Cloud/bluemix-go/authentication"
    "github.com/IBM-Cloud/bluemix-go/rest"
    "github.com/IBM-Cloud/bluemix-go/session"
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    debugFlag bool
    region    string
)

// tokenCmd represents the token command
var tokenCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "token",
    Short: "Get an IBM Cloud IAM bearer token",
    Long:  `Generate an IAM token.`,
    Run:   tokenCmdExecute,
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(tokenCmd)

    // Cobra supports Persistent Flags which will work for this command
    // and all subcommands
    tokenCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolVarP(&debugFlag, "debug", "d", false, "Enable debug")
    tokenCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&region, "region", "r", "us-south", "IBM Cloud region to target")
}

func tokenCmdExecute(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    // get the API key from the environment
    apiKey := os.Getenv("BLUEMIX_API_KEY")
    if apiKey == "" {
        log.Fatal("No API key found: please specify a BLUEMIX_API_KEY environment variable containing the API key for your IBM Cloud account")
    }

    // create a session object that will generate an IAM token and cache it
    cfg := &bluemix.Config{
        BluemixAPIKey: apiKey,
        Region:        region,
        Debug:         debugFlag,
    }
    sess, err := session.New(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    iamClient, err := authentication.NewIAMAuthRepository(cfg, rest.NewClient())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = iamClient.AuthenticateAPIKey(sess.Config.BluemixAPIKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(sess.Config.IAMAccessToken)
    spew.Dump(sess.Config)
}
```

The regions are one of a set; the SDK does a lookup to find the appropriate end-points, and the set it supports are the regions in which IBM Cloud exists.

The problem was that in my first attempt, I was using an mccp client and that is a multi-cloud cloudfoundry api that uses a different auth and endpoint caching protocol.